# Display a full screen image after using Photo Picker in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I used `Photo Picker` to retrieve images, then display them in a `LazyVGrid`. When tapping on one of the images, I'd like to open a `fullScreenCover` that displays the tapped image in that cover. But tapping for the first time it displays all the time the first image, then when I re-tap, it updates `selectedItem` and displays the correct image.

```
LazyVGrid(columns: [.init(.adaptive(minimum: 100, maximum: .infinity), spacing: 4)], spacing: 4) {
    ForEach(0..<selectedImagesData.count, id:\.self) { item in
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: selectedImagesData[item])!)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .clipped()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .onTapGesture {
                print(item)
                selectedItem = item
                print(selectedItem!)
                self.isFullscreenImage.toggle()
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isFullscreenImage) {
                NavigationView{
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: selectedImagesData[selectedItem ?? 0])!)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .toolbar {
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing){
                                Button("Fermer") {
                                    isFullscreenImage.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                            
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                                
                                ShareLink(item: bikeImage, preview: SharePreview("Photo de mon vélo", image: bikeImage)) {
                                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                                }
                            }
                            
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                                Button {
                                    selectedImagesData.remove(at: item)
                                    isFullscreenImage.toggle()
                                } label: {
                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

When tapping for the first time, I know that `item` and `selectedItem` are updated and so I don't get it doesn't "pass" to the `fullScreenCover`

Comment: try using `.fullScreenCover(item: $selectedItem) { .... }`. See the docs at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(item:ondismiss:content:)

Comment: It worked as expected with this solution! Thanks 